# NSTextField like control for entering key shortcuts - Objective-C/Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts

I've seen in some applications the control in these shots that is used to enter key shortcuts. I'd like to know if these are standard (available to everyone) or if these were built by the application's developer. I don't think it is the latter because I've seen this in many apps from different developers. Here are the images:

[image: Ready to enter shortcut]
[image: Shortcut is being entered. If you click the arrow button the text 'slides' down to reveal the first image]
[image: The shortcut has been entered]

To give one example of an app try Bowtie, though I know there's more that use this.

If this control is standard, could you tell me how to use it (what class, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one appears to be [Shortcut Recorder](http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/) from Waffle Software.

Note that the use of a rounded text field for this, while somewhat established, the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/index.html) reserves the rounded appearance for search fields.

Comment: Yep, this is definitely Shortcut Recorder.

Comment: Thanks! I have one problem, though: the downloads section is empty! How can I use this?